# Why is setInterval() running as soon as my page loads and not on click event?

Tags: setinterval

Messing around with/learning about JS timing function for the first time. What I can't figure out is why my setInterval() function is running at the start of the page instead of on the click event like shown in my code.

jfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/uLsdfn1q/6/  (ignore the names, they don't make much sense)

```
function fadeOut() {
  window.setInterval(printMsg, 1000 );
} 

exit.addEventListener("click", fadeOut())
```

I know this is probably a pretty basic question, but I honestly cannot figure out why  it is starting outside of the click event?

Comment: You're attaching the *return value* of `fadeOut` to the click handler.  Remove the `()`.  That's why its running immediately.

Comment: Ahhh  no wonder. Thank you!